# Video sphere material repeat does not seam to work in A-frame

Tags: three.js, html5-video, aframe

I run into the following issue: `<a-videosphere material="repeat: ..."` does not seam to work, while it works with a simple `a-video` tag.

I'm trying to create a half sphere and map the left half on it of an Equirectangular Video.

```
material="side: back; shader: flat; repeat: 0.5 1;"
geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100; thetaStart: 0; thetaLength: 180; phiStart: 0; phiLength: 180; segmentsWidth: 64; segmentsHeight: 64"
```

Is material repeat not supported by videospheres? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Interestingly it works with ```<a-sphere>``` If I use :
 ```<a-sphere material="src: #video_sphere; side: back; shader: flat; repeat: 0.5 1;"  
geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100; thetaStart: 0; thetaLength: 180; phiStart: 0; phiLength: 180; segmentsWidth: 64; segmentsHeight: 64"  etc... >```

Comment: I thought the `material` is setting the texture values before the `videotexture` is used, no idea why `<a-sphere>` works tho, still in any case you can always access the underlying `THREE.js` layer and set whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the video texture direcly, and there set the `repeat` value:

```
// custom component declaration
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {

    // wait until the texture is loaded
    this.el.addEventListener("materialtextureloaded", e => {
      // grab the texture
      const tex = e.detail.texture; 
      // set the repeat value
      tex.repeat.set(0.5, 1); 
    })
   }
})
// <a-videosphere foo></a-videosphere>
```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-67986851?path=index.html%3A58%3A13)

Comment: I only can see a black half sphere without any textures in your glitch example.

Comment: @Kory75 are you mobile, iOS or macOS?